# Popup after image onload

Tags: javascript, browser, popup, window

I'm trying to create a popup window with an image in it and I want the popup to be in the same aspect ratio as the image. But I only know the image dimensions on image.onload.
So what I need is a popup that comes after the image.onload. But browsers see that as an unwanted popup and will block it. Even if it's the only popup after the user's click.

I have tried creating the popup first and alter the content and sizing later on but even when that works it sometimes causes the popup window to hide in the background with no way to get it back to the front again(chrome on windows)

Is there a way to make sure the delayed popup is still `hooked` to the user's click?
Or some other suggestions.

The code that I would like to have working:

```
    selectURL: function(url) {
        // Check for images, otherwise just simply open the file by the browser.
        if(url.match(/(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$/gim)) {
            // Check if colorbox exists and use if so.
            if($.colorbox) {
                $.colorbox({
                    maxWidth:'80%',
                    maxHeight:'80%',
                    fixed: true,
                    scrolling: false,
                    href: url,
                    open: true,
                    photo: true
                });
            } else {
                // New image object so we can calculate the required popup size on load
                var myImage = new Image();
                myImage.src = url;
                // Close current window to make sure focus works
                if(typeof(popupWindow) !== 'undefined') {
                    popupWindow.close();
                }
                // Temporary loading image
                popupWindow = window.open('/images/loading.gif','popupWindow','height=400,width=600,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=200,left=200');
                if (window.focus) {
                    popupWindow.focus();
                }
                // Calculator and actual image opener :)
                myImage.onload = function() {
                    var maxWidth  = 600,
                        maxHeight = 600;
                    // Close existing popup
                    if(typeof(popupWindow) !== 'undefined') {
                        popupWindow.close();
                    }

                    if(this.width < maxWidth && this.height < maxHeight) {
                        popupWindow = window.open(this.src,'popupWindow','height='+this.height+',width='+this.width+',resizable=no,scrollbars=no,top=200,left=200');
                    } else if(this.width === this.height) {
                        popupWindow = window.open(this.src,'popupWindow','height='+maxHeight+',width='+maxWidth+',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=200,left=200');
                    } else if(this.width < this.height) {
                        popupWindow = window.open(this.src,'popupWindow','height='+maxHeight+',width='+(maxHeight / this.height * this.width)+',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=200,left=200');
                    } else {
                        popupWindow = window.open(this.src,'popupWindow','height='+(maxWidth / this.width * this.height)+',width='+maxWidth+',resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=200,left=200');
                    }
                    if (window.focus) {
                        popupWindow.focus();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            window.open(url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pop-up window that contains `loading.gif` *is* showing, then perhaps the browser does not like you opening **two** pop-ups with **one** click.

You could try opening a pop-up to `show-image.html`, in which you could show a loading image, whilst calculating the target image's size, and then resize the window using `window.resizeTo()` once you know the dimensions.

I would recommend telling `show-image.html` the target image filename by using a URL variable such as `show-image.html?image=foo.bar` or even `show-image.html?foo.bar`. Note that if you are to use such a method, you should ensure that you escape the necessary characters from the variable you gather from the URL, to avoid XSS.

I have created an example using jsFiddle. The page accepts an image's URL through a URL variable, **purely** for testing purposes - your own implementation should not include this (on *this* page). Also note that I have naturally not included protection from XSS, or `null` checks.

[This](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ad6k4/show/light/?http://www.digitalrevolutions.biz/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/blue_full.jpg) is a link to the page, using a 1920 x 1080 target image.
[This](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ad6k4/show/light/?http://hdwallpaperpics.com/wallpaper/picture/image/background.jpg) is a link to the page, using a 800   x 600­   target image.

Remember that in order to see a true **re**­load of the image, you will need to clear your browser's cache in order for the image to be loaded once again.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ad6k4/) you can see the source for the above page. If you wish to tweak this demo I recommend that you save it to a local document, as jsFiddle's frames can throw off the position calculations.

The above page provides the means of creating a pop-up containing a second page that I created. It passes the image location to the second page through the URL. As previously stated, I recommend that on the second page, you ensure that the given image name will not lead outside your website (these checks were purposefully omitted in this example).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz9nU/) is the source for the page that the first page is creating a pop-up of.

If you need further clarification or examples, let me know.

Comment: The problem does not go away when I do not first create the loading image. So it's not really about the 2nd popup but rather about the image.onload. That aside, I am indeed thinking to place the image loading script inside a different file that opens the image but are you sure window.resizeTo works in that window in all browsers?

Comment: I haven't much experience with using `resizeTo` or `moveTo` across different browsers, but I'll leave down to you to test, as I have just edited my answer with an example I have made for you. Let me know if I can help in any other way.

Comment: After some testing I noticed that in my example the pop-up is resizing to the image's size, even if the URL bar will slightly cover the image. If you don't like this you may wish to add some padding to the size it will change to and/or find the client area and subtract that from the window area, in order to find how much you must pad in each direction.

Comment: @ReneGeuze What was your final solution?